# 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException? Input validation? Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, textfieldparser

I fixed the tag, thought VBA meant visual-basic, but I'm naive in this realm.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here..

I think I'm forgetting input validation near `readfile()` but I'm not sure how to code it.. when I run the program I get a error with `currentrecord(4).` Please help.. .-.

```
Module Module1
    '                   IMPUT VARIABLES:
    Private ProductNumberInteger As Integer
    Private ProductDescriptionString As String
    Private WholeSalePriceDecimal As Decimal
    Private MarkupCodeInteger As Integer
    Private QuantitySoldInteger As Integer

    '                   CALCULATED VARIABLES AFTER PROCESSING:
    Private CalculatedMarkupAmountDecimal As Decimal '
    Private CalculatedRetailPriceDecimal As Decimal
    Private CalculatedDiscountAmountDecimal As Decimal
    Private CalculatedDiscountedPriceDecimal As Decimal
    Private CalculatedTotalEarnedDecimal As Decimal
    Private CalculatedTotalProfitDecimal As Decimal

    '                   ASSIGNED FIELDS:
    Private MarkupRateDecimal
    Private DiscountPercentRateDecimal

    '                   CONSTANT VARIABLES:
    Private MARKUP_CODE_1_DECIMAL As Decimal = 1.05
    Private MARKUP_CODE_2_DECIMAL As Decimal = 1.07
    Private MARKUP_CODE_3_DECIMAL As Decimal = 1.1
    Private MARKUP_CODE_4_DECIMAL As Decimal = 1.2
    Private MARKUP_CODE_5_DECIMAL As Decimal = 1.25

    Private CurrentRecord() As String
    Private TURKEYSALESFILE As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("THANKSWk44.txt")


    '                   ACCUMULATORS
    Private AccumFinalTotalWholesalePriceDecimal As Decimal
    Private AccumFinalTotalMarkupAmountDecimal As Decimal
    Private AccumFinalTotalProfitDecimal As Decimal
    Private AccumFinalTotalNumberOfItemsSoldThisWeekInteger As Integer

    '                   FINAL CALCULATIONS AT EOF:
    Private FinalProfitRatioDecimnal As Decimal
    Private FinalAverageMarkupDecimal As Decimal

    '                   PAGINATION CODE:
    Private PageSizeInteger As Integer = 15
    Private LineCounterInteger As Integer = 99
    Private PageNumberInteger As Integer = 1

    Private RecordSelectedBoolean As Boolean

    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    Sub Main() '                 PROGRAM STARTS HERE
        Housekeeping()
        Do While Not TURKEYSALESFILE.EndOfData
            Call ProcessRecords()
        Loop
        Call EndOfJob() '         PROGRAM ENDS HERE AFTER LOOP. EOJ CHECKS FOR EOF STATUS. 1/1 = EOF
    End Sub

    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    '   LEVEL TWO PROCESSES

    Private Sub Housekeeping()
        SetFileDelimiter() '        SETS FILE TYPE AS DELIMITED AND ADDS A COMMA
    End Sub

    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Private Sub ProcessRecords()
        ReadFile()
        RecordSelection()
        If RecordSelectedBoolean = True Then
            DetailCalculations()
            AccumulateTotals()
            WriteDetailLine()
        End If

        '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    End Sub
    Private Sub EndOfJob() '         PROGRAM END
        FinalCalculations()
        FinalOutput()
        CloseFile()
    End Sub

    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    Private Sub SetFileDelimiter()
        TURKEYSALESFILE.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        TURKEYSALESFILE.SetDelimiters(",") '         ADDS A COMMA
    End Sub

    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Private Sub ReadFile() '         READS EACH RECORD IN ORDER

        'Try
        '    TURKEYSALESFILE 'Do something dangerous
        'Catch ex As System.Exception 'catch any error
        '    'Handle the error here
        'End Try

        'Try

        'Catch
        '    Console.WriteLine("ERROR")
        'End Try

        CurrentRecord = TURKEYSALESFILE.ReadFields()
        ProductNumberInteger = CurrentRecord(0)
        ProductDescriptionString = CurrentRecord(1)
        WholeSalePriceDecimal = CurrentRecord(2)
        MarkupCodeInteger = CurrentRecord(3)
        QuantitySoldInteger = CurrentRecord(4)
    End Sub

    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Private Sub RecordSelection()
        If ProductNumberInteger = 100 - 300 Or ProductNumberInteger = 400 - 500 Or ProductNumberInteger = 600 - 700 Then
            RecordSelectedBoolean = True
        End If

    End Sub

    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Private Sub DetailCalculations() '       GENERATES CALCULATIONS THAT IS TO BE APPLIED TO THE DATA SPECIFIED

        CalculatedMarkupAmountDecimal = WholeSalePriceDecimal * MarkupRateDecimal
        CalculatedRetailPriceDecimal = WholeSalePriceDecimal + CalculatedMarkupAmountDecimal
        CalculatedDiscountAmountDecimal = CalculatedRetailPriceDecimal * DiscountPercentRateDecimal
        CalculatedDiscountedPriceDecimal = CalculatedRetailPriceDecimal - CalculatedDiscountAmountDecimal
        CalculatedTotalEarnedDecimal = CalculatedDiscountedPriceDecimal * QuantitySoldInteger
        CalculatedTotalProfitDecimal = CalculatedTotalEarnedDecimal - (QuantitySoldInteger * WholeSalePriceDecimal)

    End Sub

    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Private Sub DetermineMarkupCode()
        Select Case MarkupCodeInteger
            Case Is = 1
                MarkupCodeInteger = MARKUP_CODE_1_DECIMAL
            Case = 2
                MarkupCodeInteger = MARKUP_CODE_2_DECIMAL
            Case = 3
                MarkupCodeInteger = MARKUP_CODE_3_DECIMAL
            Case = 4
                MarkupCodeInteger = MARKUP_CODE_4_DECIMAL
            Case Else
                MarkupCodeInteger = MARKUP_CODE_5_DECIMAL
        End Select
    End Sub

    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Private Sub DetermineDiscountAmount()
        If QuantitySoldInteger = 0 - 10 Then
            DiscountPercentRateDecimal = 1.0
        Else
            If QuantitySoldInteger = 11 - 25 Then
                DiscountPercentRateDecimal = 10.0
            Else
                If QuantitySoldInteger = 26 - 40 Then
                    DiscountPercentRateDecimal = 12.5
                Else
                    If QuantitySoldInteger = 41 - 50 Then
                        DiscountPercentRateDecimal = 20.0
                    Else
                        DiscountPercentRateDecimal = 25.5
                    End If
                End If
            End If

        End If
    End Sub

    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Private Sub AccumulateTotals()
        AccumFinalTotalWholesalePriceDecimal += WholeSalePriceDecimal
        AccumFinalTotalMArkupAmountDecimal += CalculatedMarkupAmountDecimal
        AccumFinalTotalProfitDecimal += CalculatedTotalProfitDecimal
        AccumFinalTotalNumberOfItemsSoldThisWeekInteger += 1
    End Sub

    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Private Sub WriteDetailLine()
        If LineCounterInteger > PageSizeInteger Then
            WriteHeaders()
        End If
        '                   DETAIL LINE OUTPUT
        Console.WriteLine(ProductNumberInteger.ToString().PadRight(3) &
        Space(1) & ProductDescriptionString.PadLeft(12) &
        Space(1) & WholeSalePriceDecimal.ToString("N").PadLeft(5) &
        Space(2) & MarkupCodeInteger.ToString() &
        Space(1) & CalculatedMarkupAmountDecimal.ToString("N").PadLeft(5) &
        Space(2) & CalculatedRetailPriceDecimal.ToString("N").PadLeft(6) &
        Space(1) & DiscountPercentRateDecimal.ToString("n0") &
        Space(1) & CalculatedDiscountAmountDecimal.ToString("N").PadLeft(5) &
        Space(2) & QuantitySoldInteger.ToString().PadLeft(2) &
        Space(2) & CalculatedDiscountedPriceDecimal.ToString("N").PadLeft(6) &
        Space(1) & CalculatedTotalEarnedDecimal.ToString("N").PadLeft(8) &
        Space(2) & CalculatedTotalProfitDecimal.ToString("N").PadLeft(6))

        LineCounterInteger += 1
    End Sub

    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Private Sub WriteHeaders()
        Console.WriteLine("Page" & PageNumberInteger.ToString("n0").PadLeft(3) &
                          Space(18) & "Sales and Profit Report for")
        Console.WriteLine(Space(25) & "Thanks for Thanksgiving, Inc.,")
        Console.WriteLine(Space(32) & "by Nathaniel Kulinski")
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Item Desc" &
                          Space(6) & "WhlSale" &
                          Space(1) & "-Markup-" &
                          Space(2) & "Retail" &
                          Space(1) & "-Discount-" &
                          Space(1) & "Qty" &
                          Space(2) & "Discnt" &
                          Space(4) & "Total")
        Console.WriteLine("Num" &
                          Space(14) & "Price" &
                          Space(1) & "Code" &
                          Space(1) & "Amt" &
                          Space(2) & "Price" &
                          Space(5) & "%" &
                          Space(3) & "Amt" &
                          Space(1) & "Sld" &
                          Space(3) & "Price" &
                          Space(3) & "Earned" &
                          Space(2) & "Profit")
        Console.WriteLine()

        LineCounterInteger = 1
        PageNumberInteger += 1
    End Sub

    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Private Sub FinalCalculations()
        FinalProfitRatioDecimnal = AccumFinalTotalProfitDecimal / AccumFinalTotalWholesalePriceDecimal
        FinalAverageMarkupDecimal = AccumFinalTotalMarkupAmountDecimal / AccumFinalTotalNumberOfItemsSoldThisWeekInteger
    End Sub

    Private Sub FinalOutput()
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine(Space(1) & "FINAL TOTALS:")
        Console.WriteLine(Space(5) & "Wholesale Price" &
                          Space(6) & AccumFinalTotalWholesalePriceDecimal.ToString("C").PadLeft(9))
        Console.WriteLine(Space(5) & "Markup Amount" &
                          Space(8) & AccumFinalTotalMarkupAmountDecimal.ToString("C").PadLeft(9))
        Console.WriteLine(Space(5) & "Profit" &
                          Space(15) & AccumFinalTotalProfitDecimal.ToString("C").PadLeft(9))
        Console.WriteLine(Space(5) & "Items Sold" &
                          Space(12) & AccumFinalTotalNumberOfItemsSoldThisWeekInteger.ToString("N").PadLeft(5))
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine(Space(5) & "Profit Ratio" &
                          Space(11) & FinalProfitRatioDecimnal.ToString("C").PadLeft(7))
        Console.WriteLine(Space(5) & "Avg Markup Per Item" &
                          Space(5) & FinalAverageMarkupDecimal.ToString("C").PadLeft(6))
    End Sub

    Private Sub CloseFile() '        END OF PROGRAM
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter To Close Window") '       PROMPT FOR THE USER TO CLOSE THE PROGRAM
        Console.ReadLine()

        TURKEYSALESFILE.Close()
    End Sub
End Module
```

I was able to get the code to output some stuff, but it was incomplete. I think there is a issue with the imput file (this is an assignment), but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: If you get an error on 'QuantitySoldInteger = CurrentRecord(4)' then put a breakpoint on that line and see if you get a 'subscript out of range'. If so, then whatever input you are reading does not have a fourth field.

Comment: Is this the right tag?

Comment: It is a basic problem with the input file, the program fails on a line of text that does not have enough comma-separated values.  You need to test for this, CurrentRecord.Length needs to be 5.  If it is not then stop, throw an Exception, report the value of the LineNumber property so you instantly know which one is bad.